# item undifined in javascript cart

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to add items in a pure JS cart running on the localhost server. The local server runs with node and I'm using an XMLHttpRequest to reach the data (maybe could be better with fetch but it's actually running this way).

I can generate the page without problem from localserver datas,and everything works fine except the *addToCart* function:

```
var ShoppingCart = (function() {
  "use strict";

  // Cahce necesarry DOM Elements
  var productsEl = document.querySelector(".products"),
      cartEl =     document.querySelector(".shopping-cart-list"),
      productQuantityEl = document.querySelector(".product-quantity"),
      emptyCartEl = document.querySelector(".empty-cart-btn"),
      cartCheckoutEl = document.querySelector(".cart-checkout"),
      totalPriceEl = document.querySelector(".total-price");


  var products = [],
      productsInCart = [];

  var getData = function() {
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/", true);
    data.onload = function() {
      if(data.status >= 200 && data.status < 400) {
        products = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        generateProductList();
      } else {
        alert("Could not get the data!");
      }
    }

    data.onerror = function() {
      alert("Error in communication with server!");
    }

    data.send();
  }

  var setupListeners = function() {
    productsEl.addEventListener("click", addProductCallback);

    emptyCartEl.addEventListener("click", emptyCartCallback);
  }

  var addProductCallback = function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    if(el.classList.contains("add-to-cart")) {
      var elId = el.dataset.id;
      addToCart(elId);
    }
  }

  var emptyCartCallback = function(event) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        productsInCart = [];
    }
    generateCartList();
  }

  // Pretty much self explanatory function. NOTE: Here I have used template strings (ES6 Feature)
  var generateProductList = function() {
    products.forEach(function(item) {
      var productEl = document.createElement("div");
      productEl.className = "product";
      productEl.innerHTML = (`<div class="product-image">
                                <img src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="${item.name}">
                             </div>
                             <div class="product-name"><span>Product:</span> ${item.name}</div>
                             <div class="product-description"><span>Description:</span> ${item.description}</div>
                             <div class="product-price"><span>Price:</span> ${item.price} $</div>
                             <div class="product-add-to-cart">
                               <a href="#0" class="button see-more">More Details</a>
                               <a href="#0" class="button add-to-cart" data-id=${item.id}>Add to Cart</a>
                             </div>
                          </div>`);

      productsEl.appendChild(productEl);
    });
  }

    // Adds new items or updates existing one in productsInCart array
  var addToCart = function(id) {
    var obj = products[id];
    if(productsInCart.length === 0 || productFound(obj.id) === undefined) {
      productsInCart.push({product: obj, quantity: 1});
    } else {
      productsInCart.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item.product.id === obj.id) {
          item.quantity++;
        }
      });
    }
    generateCartList();
  }

  var productFound = function(productId) {
    return productsInCart.find(function(item) {
      return item.product.id === productId;
    });
  }

  // Like one before and I have also used ES6 template strings
  var generateCartList = function() {

    cartEl.innerHTML = "";

    productsInCart.forEach(function(item) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = `${item.quantity} ${item.product.name} - $${item.product.price * item.quantity}`;
      cartEl.appendChild(li);
    });

    productQuantityEl.innerHTML = productsInCart.length;

    generateCartButtons()
  }

  // Function that generates Empty Cart and Checkout buttons based on condition that checks if productsInCart array is empty
  var generateCartButtons = function() {
    if(productsInCart.length > 0) {
      emptyCartEl.style.display = "block";
      cartCheckoutEl.style.display = "block"
      totalPriceEl.innerHTML = "$ " + calculateTotalPrice();
    } else {
      emptyCartEl.style.display = "none";
      cartCheckoutEl.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var calculateTotalPrice = function() {
    return productsInCart.reduce(function(total, item) {
      return total + (item.product.price *  item.quantity);
    }, 0);
  }

  // This functon starts the whole application
  var init = function() {
    getData();
    setupListeners();
  }

  // Exposes just init function to public, everything else is private
  return {
    init: init
  };

})();

ShoppingCart.init();
```

And there is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: item.product is undefined
    generateCartList http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:105
    generateCartList http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:103
    addToCart http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:89
    addProductCallback http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:45
    setupListeners http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:36
    init http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:135
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/app2.js:145
```

I'm really a newbie at coding, sorry if the solution seems obvious.

Comment: This is way too broad. Without knowing what the Teddies API returns, there's no way we can help anyway.

Comment: Seem like there is no product with the `id` you are passing into `addToCart`.  Set a breakpoint after `var obj = products[id];` and check the value of `obj`. I bet it's `undefined`. Thus you are pushing `{product: undefined, quantity: 1}` into your cartlist. Also check if your `products` list is correctly populated with data.

Comment: @derpirscher  I confirm that the value of obj is undefined, I tried to deal with products[id] before posting but I didn't succeed at all...

Comment: Well, then you have to get your `products` straight, but we cant help you with that, because nobody knows what your `products` look like. You initially define it as array, but then access it via some `id` which seems a bit strange. You probably need something like `var obj = products.find(x => x.id == id)` But without knowing what `products` really looks like, it's just poking around in the dark.

Comment: @derpirscher You were right about defining `var obj = products.find(x => x.id == id)`. I worked about two hours but I managed to finally get an effective cart. Thanks for your help